# SVG filter is not changing the fill color

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I have a svg image which shows a little logo I`m using on a website.
This svg has three paths and in two of them i want to change the fill color to a little darker one.

```css
:root {
  --websiteColor: red;
}

.logoColor {
    fill: var(--websiteColor);
}

.logoColor:nth-of-type(2), .logoColor:nth-of-type(3) {
    fill: var(--websiteColor);
    filter: brightness(20%);
}
```

```html
<svg id="navLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="200.000000pt" height="200.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 200.000000 200.000000">
    <g stroke="none" transform="translate(0.000000,200.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
        <path class="logoColor" d="M989 1166 c-183 -164 -319 -294 -323 -308 -10 -38 -7 -300 3 -296 6 2 151 130 324 285 l314 283 6 112 c9 149 9 208 -1 208 -4 0 -150 -128 -323 -284z"/>
        <path class="logoColor" d="M1386 1162 l-318 -287 0 -159 c0 -154 0 -158 19 -145 11 8 157 138 325 289 l305 275 1 158 c0 86 -3 157 -7 156 -5 0 -151 -129 -325 -287z"/>
        <path class="logoColor" d="M572 1153 l-321 -288 0 -158 c-1 -89 3 -157 8 -155 5 2 151 131 325 287 l316 285 0 135 c0 75 3 146 6 159 4 12 2 22 -3 22 -5 0 -154 -129 -331 -287z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers don't support CSS filters on SVG elements. Some, such as Firefox do.

While the other browsers catch up you could use an SVG filter. Each CSS filter is [described in the W3C filters specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#brightnessEquivalent) so a brightness filter is this

> ```
> <filter id="brightness">
>   <feComponentTransfer>
>       <feFuncR type="linear" slope="[amount]"/>
>       <feFuncG type="linear" slope="[amount]"/>
>       <feFuncB type="linear" slope="[amount]"/>
>   </feComponentTransfer>
> </filter>
> ```